# Why go get -u takes a very long time inside a module directory, but complete quickly outside in golang?

Tags: go

I have a very slow unstable network.

### First Observation Running Locally

For example, When I run `go get -u github.com/jinzhu/gorm` in a fresh module directory (which has main.go). It prints out many lines and will never be able to complete successfully in my local environment due to a slow unstable network.

But if I run the same command outside the module directory, it can be completed in a reasonable time without any stdout.

### Second Observation Running Remotely

I have a remote VPS server which is located in USA. I create the same module directory there and run the same command inside the module on remote: `go get -u github.com/jinzhu/gorm`, and the `go.mod` will have the following content:

```
require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.39.0 // indirect
    github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb v0.0.0-20190515213511-eb9f6a1743f3 // indirect
    github.com/golang/mock v1.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/google/btree v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/google/pprof v0.0.0-20190515194954-54271f7e092f // indirect
    github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.8 // indirect
    github.com/jinzhu/inflection v0.0.0-20190603042836-f5c5f50e6090 // indirect
    github.com/kr/pty v1.1.4 // indirect
    github.com/lib/pq v1.1.1 // indirect
    go.opencensus.io v0.22.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190530122614-20be4c3c3ed5 // indirect
    golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20190510132918-efd6b22b2522 // indirect
    golang.org/x/image v0.0.0-20190523035834-f03afa92d3ff // indirect
    golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20190409202823-959b441ac422 // indirect
    golang.org/x/mobile v0.0.0-20190509164839-32b2708ab171 // indirect
    golang.org/x/mod v0.1.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190603091049-60506f45cf65 // indirect
    golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.0.0-20190523182746-aaccbc9213b0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190602015325-4c4f7f33c9ed // indirect
    golang.org/x/time v0.0.0-20190308202827-9d24e82272b4 // indirect
    golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190603152906-08e0b306e832 // indirect
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.6.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20190530194941-fb225487d101 // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.21.0 // indirect
    honnef.co/go/tools v0.0.0-20190602125119-5a4a2f4a438d // indirect
)
```

and then I run `go mod tidy`, the `go.mod` becomes:

```
require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.39.0 // indirect
    github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb v0.0.0-20190515213511-eb9f6a1743f3 // indirect
    github.com/google/go-cmp v0.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.8
    github.com/jinzhu/inflection v0.0.0-20190603042836-f5c5f50e6090 // indirect
    github.com/lib/pq v1.1.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190530122614-20be4c3c3ed5 // indirect
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.6.0 // indirect
)
```

But if I remove the `require(...)` section completely from `go.mod` and then execute `go mod tidy`, I get the following content in `go.mod`:

```
require github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.8
```

Just one require. And with this one line, I run `go build`, the module can be built and ran successfully without any problems.

So I am very confused what `go get -u` really does in my module directory.

My two questions:

- Should I run `go get -u` inside module directory or can I simply run it outside module directory?
- Why `go get -u` outside the module directory can complete easily? Dose it do the same download/upgrade compared to running inside the module directory?

I am using the latest stable golang go1.12.5. Because `go get -u` calls `git` and `git` calls `curl`, but `curl` is very bad on unstable network (compared to `wget`). I am unable to complete `go get -u` inside the module directory. I will get many `error: RPC failed; The remote end hung up unexpectedly; fatal: early EOF; fatal: index-pack failed;`. I don't know if there is a workaround for this problem or not. But I can use `go get -u` outside the module directory though.

(Incidentally, if `go get` can use wget, it will work in my local environment. I never have any problems with wget and wget will finally complete the download after waiting for a long time. But unfortunately, wget is not a preferred tool by the current dev world).

Answer (score 0):

> Should I run go get -u inside module directory or can I simply run it outside module directory?

If you're using modules, you need to run it inside your module directory if you want it to actually update your `go.mod` / `go.sum` files.

> Why go get -u outside the module directory can complete easily? Dose it do the same download/upgrade compared to running inside the module directory?

They're pretty different in behavior. `go help get`, `go help module-get` and `go help modules` should explain some of the differences and in your case check [the module doc](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies):

> A common mistake is thinking go get -u foo solely gets the latest version of foo. In actuality, the -u in go get -u foo or go get -u foo@latest means to also get the latest versions for all of the direct and indirect dependencies of foo.

The go.mod for gorm includes a lot of stuff (https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/go.mod) including drivers for every possible database it supports, which seems pretty intense. Since you're just doing a blanket `-u` and not specifying `@v1.9.3` or whatever, it's trying to update all of Gorm's dependencies (and the dependencies' dependencies!) in module-aware mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I checked `go help get`, it states that `The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named packages
and their dependencies.`. This should be the same as what it does for module-get -u. No? Btw, I know module-get will update go.mod. But the current behavior is `go get -u` can be completed really fast outside module directory and will take an infinite long time inside the module.

Comment: that's because `go get` in a module context operates completely differently than `go get` in a module context. `-u` without a version number on it in a module context will also update all that module's dependency's versions, which is not what it does in a non-module "classic" global context.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But I am very sorry that I don't understand what you mean. Let's say `go get -u foo`. from `go help get`, it will update (1) the package foo and (2) all foo's dependencies to the latest in global context. Then what do you mean that is different from module context? I knew it did something different. But I don't understand what the difference is from your explanation.You are always saying the foo package and foo's dependencies. That's right and that is what it dose in global context too. Unless `go help get` is wrong.

Comment: Are you saying that `go get -u foo` in global context will only update foo's package? and `go get -u foo` in module context will update foo's package and foo's dependencies? Is this what you mean? I am confused what you mean.